# getUserMedia in an https iframe invoked by an http page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, iframe, webrtc

I am trying to get user's permission for my webRTC implementation. I have an http website where i am allowing the user to make calls. i have embedded an iframe that would be loaded on user click (source provided to an otherwise empty iframe). The source of the iframe is secure page.

I get an error stating that i cant use getUserMedia function in an unsecure page.

Any suggestions/help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide more information please. If you read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it will tell you the kind of information you should provide to help us answer your question. Off the top of my head, the javascript code that does the call to getUserMedia will have to be served using https, so you may need to move that to the iframe or have the whole page in https

Comment: The iframe  is being served over https.

Answer (score 3):

getUserMedia requires a secure origin in Chrome. The origin is your http page so this will not work, you need https.

See [here](https://tokbox.com/blog/the-impact-of-googles-new-chrome-security-policy-on-webrtc/) for further information.

Comment: The page is http but the  iframe is https. Shouldn't that work?

Comment: No. that would allow a http page to grab the users camera which is not the intention of requiring a secure origin.